# Exception Loading SKScene after Xcode 8.1 Update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

After updating XCode to 8.1, I'm code throws a runtime exception when it tries to initialize the SKScene

```
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") { // Exception is thrown on this line
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.fill
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
```

Comment: was it GameScene(fileNamed:) or SKScene(fileNamed:)

Comment: This is the sample game sample project from XCode, it starts it out as SKScene(fileNamed:)

Comment: If the template project is crashing "out of the box", you should definitely [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Well, I've made changes to the project later, but it was working fine the night before, but after 8.1 update it started crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is an issue with Assets and XCode 8.1, I deleted an asset from the SKScene that seemed to be causing the trouble and it's working fine.

I now have a different issue with the Texture Atlas.

So finally it seems the issue is that in XCode 8.1, you must have the scales for all the images in your assets catalog.

Once I placed the images for the 2x and 3x, the program stopped crashing.